# Is there way to require ctrl + alt + del at login screen?

Tags: linux, security, login

Same way a Windows computer can have a secure login screen that requires ctrl alt del to get through. Does Linux have a way to configure this for itself? Is there anything equivalent?

Comment: Brother I just want a bit more security. Or do you think it won't make a difference?

Comment: It won't make a difference.

Comment: @DopeGhoti okay, but is there a way to do it?

Comment: Legitimate question: How does requiring Ctrl+Alt+Del be pressed before login increase security in any way?

Comment: @Fox, A question you could put in security.SE or maybe some other. But briefly, if I've understood correctly, Windows catches that key combination at a very low level, so that regular applications can't catch it. Instead, pressing it signals the (trusted) login program to hop to the foreground. Makes it harder/impossible to create a fake login screen.

Comment: @Fox: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_attention_key

Comment: Thanks Jeff and ilkkachu! Found it at [What's the rationale behind Ctrl-Alt-Del for login](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/34972) on security.se, and the accepted answer even gives a method for the Linux console (but not X).  Neat!

Answer (score 4):

Security in using a predefined key combination at login is to catch and process the key sequence at low level. Password capturing trojans running in user-space can not therefore use the same sequence in order to masquerade as a legitimate login prompt. (To be secure, this of course also requires your users won't enter their credentials when they have not used the required key combination).

Linux has a Secure Attention Key (SAK) mechanism for configuring such key sequence. When SAK is triggered, any processes which have `/dev/console` open will be killed. This should restart display manager which in turn should display the system login screen. Details are provided in the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/SAK.txt).

Comment: Additionally, forever ago when we used a simple inittab file you could define what exactly the ctrl+alt+del key combo did - exec a script, ignore, go into some other runlevel (reboot, etc)